# Load data from MySQL database to textboxes on dropdown list click

Tags: php, html, mysql

i got this code

```html
<?php

  include("konek.php");

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('psc_db');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM komponen ORDER BY komponen_id";
//$query = "SELECT * FROM taxi_services ORDER BY SID";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql); //$conn

if(isset($_POST["loadbtn"]))
{
    $id = (integer) $_POST["codes"];

    $query = "SELECT nama_komponen, ekuivalen_sks, ekuivalen_jam FROM komponen WHERE komponen_id = '$id' ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $details = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $savedName = $details["nama_komponen"];
    $savedJam = $details["ekuivalen_sks"];
    $savedSks = $details["ekuivalen_jam"];
}

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="upserv">
<b id="caption2">Planning</b>
<br/><br/>
    <form name="upServForm" method="post" >
        <?php
        $dropdown = "<select name='codes'>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
        {
            $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['komponen_id']}'>{$row['komponen_id']}</option>";
        }
        $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
    ?>
     Service ID  <?php echo $dropdown; ?> <input type="submit" value="Load" name="loadbtn">
        <table width="300" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="upName" style="text-align:right" value="<? echo $savedName; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>ekuivalen sks</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="upCost" style="text-align:right" value="<? echo $savedJam; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>ekuivalen jam</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="upActive" style="text-align:right" value="<? echo $savedSks; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="buttons">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" /> <input type="submit" value="Save" name="updatebtn" />
</div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and the result is something like this

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2jAL.png)

I still haven't sucessfully display the data when I click the button. 
I got the example code from another post, and I tried it and above is the result(but I'm still fail).
All I want to do is to display the data into the textbox without the load button

Can you help me coding this code please, thank you

Comment: Might be that shorttags are disabled. Try using `<?php` instead of just `<?`.

Comment: For more information on opening tags, see [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

Comment: it worked, thanks!! but I the data is stuck on data number 1, everytime I choose another data it will gone back to data number 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think short tags is not configured in your server. 
you have to replace `<?` with `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must stop using PHP short tags( `<? ?>` ) or in case that you need or are used to use the enable it on the **php.ini** file on your server. 
The thing that happens is that the php handler does not recognize the code inside the value attribute of the input because of the short tag and does not evaluate it. That's all, enable short tags and you can do some stuff like `<?=` for `<? echo`, nice...
In your php.ini file,

**short_open_tag** stands for the opening and closing `<? ?>` notation.

**asp_tags** stands for `<% %>` notation

I have created this to simulate your problem

```
<?php 
    if ($_POST['btnsubmit']){
        echo $_POST['codes'];
    }
?>

<html>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <select name="codes">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>   
        <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="send"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And works as expected, other thing is that if you want to keep track of the selected option on the select input you have to add a conditional selected clause to the options of the input that prints the selected="selected" attribute on the option based on the previous submitted value.

Comment: asp_tags does not stand for <?= notation, it's <% notation iirc being that it's ASP.

Comment: yup, that the problem and change it to <?php solve it,  but I the data is stuck on data number 1, everytime I choose another data it will gone back to data number 1

Comment: Yes, sorry for that mistake on asp tags, I wrote it wrong. Thanks for the correction